# I Can't "Don't word wrap"

Tags: notebooks, formatting, text

OS : windows 10 / Mathematica version : 12.2

1. Close all mathematica process and start new mathematica.exe
2. See what is checked in Menubar - Format - Word Wrapping :
   `Wrap at Window Width` is checked
3. Change it to `Don't word wrap`
4. See what is checked in Menubar - Format - Word Wrapping :
   `Don't word wrap` is checked (it's still ok)
5. Type anything on a notebook (typed number 1)
6. See what is checked in Menubar - Format - Word Wrapping :
   `Wrap at Window Width` is checked. Strange.

[image]

It seems that doing something in the notebook (like just typing number 1)
initialize the Word Wrapping setting. (set it to `Wrap at Window Width`)

Is this normal behavior ?
If it is, what does this phenomenon mean ?

Comment: Version13.1  I look like the word wrap formatting is local to the cell. Try placing the cursor inside the input cell and check the word wrap.

Comment: Thank you, I am 12.2 and seems word wrap formatting is local to the cell, either. 
I am almost new to the setting so I can't say more about it. But Judging from the comment above, until recently, the setting might be global.